# Copy shape key to a different object with similar geometry

Tags: shape-keys, interpolation

Is it possible to copy a shape key between objects with similar geometry? Specifically, I am looking to transfer shape keys from a higher poly mesh to a lower poly mesh that are very similar in shape, but have different topology.

Contrived example:
Here I have two meshes with similar geometry.
[image: Example image 1]
The mesh on the left has a shape key.
[image: Example image 2]
If I align the mesh on the right with the mesh on the left, such that the verts are *generally* next to their counterparts... (this will have varying degrees of error for more complex shapes with different topology and scale)
[image: Example image 3]
...can the per-vertex transition data for the first mesh's shape key be interpolated and copied to the second mesh? Can I adjust the interpolation strategy? (similar to how vertex weighting can be copied between dissimilar meshes with varying interpolation methods)

Comment: Even if you have equal geometry, but different vertices order, transfer will fail. Shapekeys are very strict to this. Try shrinkwrap or mesh/surface deform to mimic shapekey from source object.

Comment: Also depending on your requirements you can create a Lattice animated with Shape Keys that can be used for multiple objects.